# ionic - sqllite insert multiple rows

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework

sorry for the basic question but I am trying to understand which is the best way to do this.
I am new to promises and angular/typescript/ionic/javascript.

I have an array and I want to insert in a SQLlite table one row for each element of the array.

**-------------------**

**EDIT my code looks like this now and it kinda works, but wondering if there is a better way (for sure)**

```
for(var a=0; a<this.myarray.length; a++){

  this.insertquery(this.myarray[a].parameter1,this.myarray[a].parameter2);

}
insertquery(value1,value2){

   this.databaseObj.executeSql('INSERT INTO mytable(field1, field2) VALUES ("'+value1+'","'+value2+'")',[])
.then(() => {
    alert('Row Inserted!');
})
.catch(e => {
    alert('error ' + JSON.stringify(e))
});
}
```

**-------------------------------------------**

At the moment my code looks this

> ```
>  for(var a=0; a<this.myarray.length; a++){
> ```

```
      this.databaseObj.executeSql('INSERT INTO mytable(filed1, field2) VALUES ('+this.myarray[a].property1+','+this.myarray[a].property2+');')

      .then(() => {
        alert('Row Inserted!');

      })
      .catch(e => {
        alert('error ' + JSON.stringify(e))
      });

    }
```

Apart that it's not working because of I don't know which reason :) I am sure that this is incorrect from the "promise" point of view and there must be a better way to do that.

Do you have any hint on how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example how to add data to sqlite:

use the following command to insert: **INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Table**

```
   const readline = require('readline');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

    let db;

    // database is not existing
        console.log('open database and create table');
        db = new sqlite3.Database('./event.db',() => {
          db.run('CREATE TABLE logTable(logfile TEXT,logdate TEXT,referto TEXT, area TEXT,status TEXT,action TEXT)',() => {
    var res = ['mylog.txt','03.10.2018','m1','Area1','ok','Load']
   // map fields to entry
      entryDate = '-';
      entry.logfile = res[0];
      entry.logdate = res[1];

      entry.action = res[5]; 
      entry.area = res[2];
      entry.referto = res[3];
      entry.status = res[4];


    db.run("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO logTable (logfile, logdate, referto, area, status, action) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",
     [entry["logfile"], entry["logdate"], entry["referto"], entry["area"], entry["status"], entry["action"]], function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err.message);
      } else {
          db.close();
      }
      // get the last insert id
      console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
          });
```

see also [here](https://github.com/src-mgra/node-sqlite-chart/blob/master/addData2Sqlite.js)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am able to insert one row to sqqllite (I also fixed the error in the previous query). The problem is how to add multiple rows, one for each element in my array. I tried with a for cycle, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with async stuff and I ended up doing an SELECT insert this process does a single insert statement.
I share to you my code

```
/*
    "params" its my JSON array, you could send just a simple array or 2d matrix
*/
CreateMany(storage: SQLiteObject, tableName: string, params: any[]) {
    // Get keys from the first JSON in array
    const keys = Object.keys(params[0]).filter(key => params[0][key].constructor != Object && !Array.isArray(params[0][key]));
    
    // Get SELECT UNION string
    let selectInsert: string = params.map(param => Object.values(param)).join(' union all SELECT ');

    // Build my query
    const query: string = `
        INSERT INTO ${tableName} (${keys.join()}) 
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT ${selectInsert}
        );
    `;

    return storage.executeSql(query, []);
}
```